# Not able to get AAC codec running when connecting Bluetooth headsets in Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: drivers, sound, bluetooth, aac

I'm not able to get the AAC codec working when I connect my Bluetooth headsets, only SBC and SBC-XQ are available to me which results in losing the connection entirely or the quality becomes worse, sometimes it even switches to hands-free-system audio quality for some weird reason. I cannot even succesfully recreate this behavior because sometimes it works (even though audio doesn't sound too good). This only happens in Ubuntu 22.10. I've used elementary OS (current version), Fedora 37 and OpenSUSE Tumbleweed (both with GNOME) and KaOS (KDE-centric distro) where I don't have this problem.

My Hardware:
HP 255 G8 Notebook PC -
AMD Ryzen™ 3 3250U with Radeon™ Graphics × 4 - AMD Radeon™ Vega 3 Graphics - 8GB RAM/SSD

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, appereantly codecs are not shipped with default install.
[This](https://launchpad.net/%7Eaglasgall/+archive/ubuntu/pipewire-extra-bt-codecs) does install required codecs:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:aglasgall/pipewire-extra-bt-codecs
sudo apt update
```

Restart and you will see the AAC codec in the sound configuration while using your bluetooth headset. Like This: [my configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ob70.png)

Comment: thx a lot, kinda stumbled upon this solution (and PPA) but also forgot I asked here  and it worked better with SBC so I didn't bother that much anymore. Tried the PPA and it works, so this is solved 